# Web page not reachable

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I am installing a Musicbox Frontend on a Debian Server.
Everything works on the local server, by accessing 127.0.0.1:6680.

On other machines in the same subnet i can't reach this webpage by using 192.168.0.50:6680

I added the port to the ip-table, i have this output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:6600
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:6680

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:6680
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:6600
```

When i use nmap to inspect the ports, the port doesn't seem to be reachable

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-02-08 03:32 Romance Standard     Time

NSE: Loaded 118 scripts for scanning.

NSE: Script Pre-scanning.

 Initiating ARP Ping Scan at 03:32

 Scanning 192.168.0.50 [1 port]

 Completed ARP Ping Scan at 03:32, 0.13s elapsed (1 total hosts)

 Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 03:32

Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 03:32, 0.02s elapsed

Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 03:32

Scanning 192.168.0.50 [1000 ports]

 Discovered open port 22/tcp on 192.168.0.50

  Discovered open port 3389/tcp on 192.168.0.50

Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 03:32, 0.21s elapsed (1000 total ports)

Initiating Service scan at 03:32

 Scanning 2 services on 192.168.0.50

 Completed Service scan at 03:33, 6.01s elapsed (2 services on 1 host)

 Initiating OS detection (try #1) against 192.168.0.50

 NSE: Script scanning 192.168.0.50.

Initiating NSE at 03:33

Completed NSE at 03:33, 1.12s elapsed    

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.50

Host is up (0.0023s latency).

Not shown: 998 closed ports

 PORT     STATE SERVICE       VERSION

22/tcp   open  ssh           OpenSSH 6.0p1 Debian 4+deb7u2 (protocol 2.0)

3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server xrdp

MAC Address: XXXXXXXXXXXX

Device type: general purpose

Running: Linux 3.X

OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3

OS details: Linux 3.11 - 3.14

Uptime guess: 0.031 days (since Sun Feb 08 02:47:48 2015)

Network Distance: 1 hop

TCP Sequence Prediction: Difficulty=262 (Good luck!)

    IP ID Sequence Generation: All zeros

Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel



TRACEROUTE
HOP RTT     ADDRESS
1   2.27 ms 192.168.0.50
```

Answer (score 0):

the Musicbox listen address is 127.0.0.1:6680? if so you can't reach this webpage by using 192.168.0.50:6680, you can inspect it by using `netstat -anop | grep 6680`